# Genesis + Ajax + Jquery | Failling to call action

Tags: posts, jquery, ajax, templates

I want to execute an action, without realoading my page. I folllow this tuto
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

But each time my page reloads, and I can't have the result value. Here is my code :

**In custom-login.php**

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'ck_do_login_form' );
function ck_do_login_form() {

     // Enqueue sticky menu script - Crunchify Tips
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'crunchify_enqueue_script' );

    // Test love
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );

    // Content
    add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'vivi_logged' );
}

function post_love_add_love() {
    $whatever = 1;
    $whatever++;
    echo $love;
    wp_die();
}

function crunchify_enqueue_script() {  

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-2.1.0', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'user-login', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/user-login.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

    //Here we create a javascript object variable called "youruniquejs_vars". We can access any variable in the array using youruniquejs_vars.name_of_sub_variable
    wp_localize_script( 'user-login', 'userlogin_object', 
        array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'the_issue_key' => $the_issue_key) 
    );      
}

function vivi_logged() {

$love_text = '<form id="ticket" name="ticket" >  
                          <fieldset>  
                            <input type="hidden" name="tkt_id" value="' . $TKT_ID . '" required/>
                            <input type="number" name="TKT_qty_new" value="' . $TKT_qty . '" required/>
                            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />  
                          </fieldset>  
                          </form><div id="form-messages"></div></form><div id="form-messages2"></div><div id="form-messages3"></div>';

            echo $love_text;

}
```

**In user-login.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.love-button', function(event) { Triger on click href
    jQuery('#ticket').change( function(event){  

        jQuery("#form-messages").html("TEST 1");
        event.preventDefault();

        var postData = {
            'action': 'post_love_add_love',
            'whatever': userlogin_object.the_issue_key
        };

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : userlogin_object.ajaxurl,
            data : postData,
            success: function(response) {
                alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                jQuery("#form-messages2").html("TEST REQUEST");
            }
        });

        jQuery("#form-messages3").html("TEST 3");
    }); 
});
```

**Result**

Its display 
"TEST1" and "TEST3"
Then my page realoads

Do you have an idea to prevent this reload and to have my result "TEST REQUEST" ?

Thanks a lot for your help,

---------------- **EDIT V2 - 24/03/2016** ----------------

Thanks to Milo and  Userabuser comments, I change my php.
Still have 0 in my respons

**In user-login.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    jQuery('#ticket').on('keyup click', 'input[name="submit"], input[name="TKT_qty_new"]', function(event){  

        //prevent the default submit action of the form...
        event.preventDefault();

        if ( event.type === 'click' && event.target.name !== 'submit' ) {
            return false;
        }        

        doAjaxRequest();

    }); 

    function doAjaxRequest() {

        //issue ajax request
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : userlogin_object.ajaxurl,
            dataType: "json",
            data : {
                'action': 'post_love_add_love'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                //process success response
                alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                jQuery("#form-messages2").html("TEST REQUEST : " + response);
            }
        });

    }      

});
```

**In custom-login.php**

```
 add_action( 'get_header', 'ck_do_login_form' );
function ck_do_login_form() {

    // Start session if doesn't already exists
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }

    // Remove the comment form
    add_filter( 'comments_open', '__return_false' ); 

    // Remove the list of comments
    add_filter( 'comments_array', '__return_empty_array' );
}

/**
* Enqueue sticky menu script - Crunchify Tips
*/
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'crunchify_enqueue_script' );
function crunchify_enqueue_script() {  

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-2.1.0', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'user-login', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/user-login.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

    //Here we create a javascript object variable called "youruniquejs_vars". We can access any variable in the array using youruniquejs_vars.name_of_sub_variable
    wp_localize_script( 'user-login', 'userlogin_object', 
        array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'the_issue_key' => $the_issue_key) 
    );      
}


    // Test love Ajax
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_love_add_love', 'post_love_add_love' );
function post_love_add_love() {
    $love = 10;
    wp_send_json($love);
    exit;
}

/**
* Fonction quand l'internaute est connecté : Informations + Stages postés
*/
remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );
add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'vivi_logged' );
function vivi_logged() {

$love_text = '<form id="ticket" name="ticket" >  
                          <fieldset>  
                            <input type="hidden" name="tkt_id" value="' . $TKT_ID . '" required/>
                            <input type="number" name="TKT_qty_new" value="' . $TKT_qty . '" required/>
                            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />  
                          </fieldset>  
                          </form><div id="form-messages"></div></form><div id="form-messages2"></div><div id="form-messages3"></div>';

            echo $love_text;
}
```

Comment: you can't add `wp_ajax` actions on `get_header`, it doesn't get called on ajax requests.

Comment: Thx Milo. I change (see above) but I got the same results.

Comment: I find something. When I click without releasing my click, it's working. But when I just clik on my submit form, this reloads my page.

Comment: You have not defined your event handler to handle the submit button; see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are clicking the "submit" button in your form (which I am assuming); it will submit the form performing the default method `GET` where no method is specified.

You need to ensure that you prevent the default submit action.

In your JavaScript; you are listening for a `change` event on the entire form, instead you should bind to the submit button.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    jQuery('#ticket').on('click', '#submit', function(event){  

        //prevent the default submit action of the form...
        event.preventDefault();

        //issue ajax request
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : userlogin_object.ajaxurl,
            data : {
                'action': 'post_love_add_love',
                'whatever': userlogin_object.the_issue_key
            },
            success: function(response) {
                //process success response
                alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                jQuery("#form-messages2").html("TEST REQUEST");
            }
        });

    }); 

});
```

If you really must listen for `change` events; target the field that receives input, in your case it is one field only `name="TKT_qty_new"`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    jQuery('#ticket').on('keyup click', 'input[name="submit"], input[name="TKT_qty_new"]', function(event){  

        //prevent the default submit action of the form...
        event.preventDefault();

        if ( event.type === 'click' && event.target.name !== 'submit' ) {
            return false;
        }        

        doAjaxRequest();

    }); 

    function doAjaxRequest() {

        //issue ajax request
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : userlogin_object.ajaxurl,
            data : {
                'action': 'post_love_add_love',
                'whatever': userlogin_object.the_issue_key
            },
            success: function(response) {
                //process success response
                alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                jQuery("#form-messages2").html("TEST REQUEST");
            }
        });

    }      

});
```

Comment: Really better, thanks for that. Last thing. Now in my response I got "'Got this from the server: 0'. Even I set the default variable $love = 1.

Comment: `wp_die()` when passed no `$message` parameter, will internally call PHP's `die()` function, except WordPress will pass `'0'` as a string `die('0')`. Instead you can simply do `echo $love; exit;` Make sure `$love` is defined with a value though...

Comment: Same result with my : function post_love_add_love() {
 $love = 10;
 echo  $love;
 exit;
}

Comment: move your `wp_ajax_*` hooks outside of `genesis_entry_content` and you have a duplicate call to `wp_ajax_post_love_add_love`. Also you might need to `json_encode()` your response. So instead do `wp_send_json($love);`

Comment: Also you are duplicating your hooks in `ck_do_login_form` callback... remove them from there.

Comment: I change the actions have you said. Same results. Still have the 0. I edited my first post to see the new code.

Comment: Where is your `custom-login.php` file... where are you including it? Are you including it directly into a theme file? Or is it an include within your `functions.php` file?

Comment: Is in /wp-content/themes/altitude-pro/custom-template

Comment: Ok its work on function.php !! Thx a lot.

Comment: Is it possible to put it in other folder template ?

Comment: You can keep the logic contained within it's own file, but you need to include it into the scope of `functions.php` file.

Comment: I can now use  echo $love;wp_die();